# How to ignore __generated__ files with eslint

Tags: node.js, typescript, intellij-idea, eslint

I have a type generator tool that generates types for me with in my src.   I want eslint to ignore those files how do I set it up to do that?

I tried to add the following glob entry to .eslintignore:

`**/__generated__/**`

but that had no effect

Comment: do your generated files have .d.ts extensions? You could add *.d.ts to the .eslintignore file.

Comment: nope: plain .ts files

Comment: Ignore patterns in `.eslintignore` behave according to the [.gitignore spec](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) , so `**/foo` matches file or directory `foo` anywhere.